# A Client for IBM DB2 7.2 AIX

Tags: db2, client, db2-luw, jdbc-odbc

- I have an old AIX box running IBM DB2 7.2.
- I need to get some data from some of the instances of some of the databases

  - I tried Quest TOAD for Data Analysts which gives me the driver is not compatible
  - I tried IBM Data Studio 4.1.2 : can connect but "invalid operation " and then shows nothing
  - I tried SQL Workbench/J 122: idem

So I wonder what client/tool I can use to browse the Db2 instance-databases from a Windows 7 laptop (there is no 7.2 mentioned on this overview: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21363866)

**UPDATE**
Installing the version 9.1 client still gives me "SQL5048N The release level of the database client is not supported by the release level of the database server"

Comment: Why not just log directly in to the AIX box and extract data directly instead of trying to get a client working?  This seems like it would be a much less complicated solution.

Comment: I've thought about that scenario also but it's a complicated scenario. that will be my alternative. I will probably have to develop more stuff around it to extract stuff from the ibm ondemand database and extract individual files which are pointed to from the db. It will save me a lot of time doing this in one environment especially since this is just one of the boxes I need to extract and combine data with,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern DB2 JDBC drivers (JCC, also called type 4) are not compatible with DB2 7.2 --  you will need either type 1 ("net") or type 2 ("app") JDBC driver, both rely on native DB2 CLI libraries installed.

Typically DB2 clients are backwards-compatible up to 2 versions down, so version 9.5 and 9.1 drivers should work, at least partially (with the exception of features unsupported by the version 7.2 server).

[Download](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27016878) and install the full Data Server Client then you can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17088241/db2-cant-connect-to-the-server/17089972#17089972) for how to configure client connectivity.

Comment: Thanks, i tried to install db2-winx74-client-9.1.1200.483-FP012 but of course it fails with an error saying that it found previous installations that it wants to migrate but it can not find where the installations are. So I have no clue what should be uninstalled, log files show no info further. So have to keep searching.

Comment: ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42277948/ibm-db2-data-server-client-install-fails