# IBM Db2 data server client install fails

Tags: installation, db2, db2-luw

With reference to to [A Client for IBM DB2 7.2 AIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42274610/a-client-for-ibm-db2-7-2-aix)

I'm trying to install the windows Db2 client: DB2-winx64-client-9.1.1200.483-FP012   (see: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24033024).This fails because it detected previous level of Db2 products installed but it can not determine where is what installed (I don't know what should be uninstalled).

[image: message1]

[image: message2]

[image: message3]

[image: message4]

I tried to check the log files but they dont give me a clue:

```
=== Logging started: 16-2-2017  16:00:26 ===
Action 16:00:26: INSTALL.
Action start 16:00:26: INSTALL.
Action 16:00:26: AppSearch. Searching for installed applications
Action start 16:00:26: AppSearch.
AppSearch: Property: IE4FOUND, Signature: sigShdocvwISUS
AppSearch: Property: XPFOUND, Signature: sigKernel32
AppSearch: Property: PROP_RSP_DB2_OLEDB_GUID, Signature: PROP_RSP_DB2_OLEDB_GUID
AppSearch: Property: PROP_RSP_DB2_OLEDB_ADVANCED_PAGE_GUID, Signature: PROP_RSP_DB2_OLEDB_ADVANCED_PAGE_GUID
AppSearch: Property: PROP_RSP_DB2_OLEDB_CONNECTION_PAGE_GUID, Signature: PROP_RSP_DB2_OLEDB_CONNECTION_PAGE_GUID
AppSearch: Property: PROP_RSP_DB2_OLEDB_ENUMERATOR_GUID, Signature: PROP_RSP_DB2_OLEDB_ENUMERATOR_GUID
AppSearch: Property: PROP_RSP_DB2_OLEDB_ERROR_LOOKUP_GUID, Signature: PROP_RSP_DB2_OLEDB_ERROR_LOOKUP_GUID
Action ended 16:00:26: AppSearch. Return value 1.
Action 16:00:26: LaunchConditions. Evaluating launch conditions
Action start 16:00:26: LaunchConditions.
Action ended 16:00:26: LaunchConditions. Return value 1.
Action 16:00:26: CheckProductUseJavaCA.
Action start 16:00:26: CheckProductUseJavaCA.
Action ended 16:00:26: CheckProductUseJavaCA. Return value 1.
Action 16:00:26: SetupInitialization.
Action start 16:00:26: SetupInitialization.
Info 2898.For Tahoma8 textstyle, the system created a 'Tahoma' font, in 0 character set, of 13 pixels height.
Info 2898.For TahomaBold10 textstyle, the system created a 'Tahoma' font, in 0 character set, of 16 pixels height.
Info 2898.For TahomaBold8 textstyle, the system created a 'Tahoma' font, in 0 character set, of 13 pixels height.
DEBUG: Error 2836:  The control image_noJava on the dialog SetupInitialization can not take focus
Internal Error 2836. SetupInitialization, image_noJava
Action 16:00:26: SetupInitialization. Dialog created
Action ended 16:00:26: SetupInitialization. Return value 1.
Action 16:00:26: FindRelatedProducts. Searching for related applications
Action start 16:00:26: FindRelatedProducts.
Action ended 16:00:26: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 1.
Action 16:00:26: ValidateProductID.
Action start 16:00:26: ValidateProductID.
Action ended 16:00:26: ValidateProductID. Return value 1.
Action 16:00:26: Check32bitDB2on64bitSystemCA.
Action start 16:00:26: Check32bitDB2on64bitSystemCA.
Action ended 16:00:26: Check32bitDB2on64bitSystemCA. Return value 1.
Action 16:00:26: CostInitialize. Computing space requirements
Action start 16:00:26: CostInitialize.
Action ended 16:00:26: CostInitialize. Return value 1.
Action 16:00:26: FileCost. Computing space requirements
Action start 16:00:26: FileCost.
Action ended 16:00:26: FileCost. Return value 1.
Action 16:00:26: ResolveSource.
Action start 16:00:26: ResolveSource.
Action ended 16:00:26: ResolveSource. Return value 1.
Action 16:00:26: setInstallLangCA.
Action start 16:00:26: setInstallLangCA.
Action ended 16:00:26: setInstallLangCA. Return value 1.
Action 16:00:26: ResetREINSTALLCA.
Action start 16:00:26: ResetREINSTALLCA.
Action ended 16:00:26: ResetREINSTALLCA. Return value 1.
Action 16:00:26: SetInitialPropertiesCA.
Action start 16:00:26: SetInitialPropertiesCA.
Action ended 16:00:26: SetInitialPropertiesCA. Return value 1.
Action 16:00:26: StreamLibrarysCA.
Action start 16:00:26: StreamLibrarysCA.
1: The current directory for the process has now been changed to C:\Users\LOCALA~1.009\AppData\Local\Temp\_DB20000
Action ended 16:00:27: StreamLibrarysCA. Return value 1.
Action 16:00:27: InitializeURERunTimeLocationCA.
Action start 16:00:27: InitializeURERunTimeLocationCA.
Action ended 16:00:27: InitializeURERunTimeLocationCA. Return value 1.
Action 16:00:27: EnableTracingUISequenceCA.
Action start 16:00:27: EnableTracingUISequenceCA.
Action ended 16:00:27: EnableTracingUISequenceCA. Return value 1.
Action 16:00:27: EnableUREObserversCA.
Action start 16:00:27: EnableUREObserversCA.
Action ended 16:00:27: EnableUREObserversCA. Return value 1.
Action 16:00:27: setProcessIDOfLauncherCA.
Action start 16:00:27: setProcessIDOfLauncherCA.
Action ended 16:00:27: setProcessIDOfLauncherCA. Return value 1.
Action 16:00:27: DetectOldDB2ProductsCA.
Action start 16:00:27: DetectOldDB2ProductsCA.
Action ended 16:00:27: DetectOldDB2ProductsCA. Return value 1.
Action 16:00:27: IsolateComponents.
Action start 16:00:27: IsolateComponents.
Action ended 16:00:27: IsolateComponents. Return value 1.
Action 16:00:27: CostFinalize. Computing space requirements
Action start 16:00:27: CostFinalize.
Action ended 16:00:27: CostFinalize. Return value 1.
Action 16:00:27: CreateTextExtenderLvLFileCA.
Action start 16:00:27: CreateTextExtenderLvLFileCA.
1: Successfully created registry entries for selected features.
Action ended 16:00:27: CreateTextExtenderLvLFileCA. Return value 1.
Action 16:00:27: CommonGuiSilentCA.
Action start 16:00:27: CommonGuiSilentCA.
1: ERROR:The DB2 Setup was unable to determine the location of the installation
that is being migrated.  This installation cannot be migrated.
CustomAction CommonGuiSilentCA returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
Action ended 16:01:04: CommonGuiSilentCA. Return value 3.
Action 16:01:04: SetupCompleteError.
Action start 16:01:04: SetupCompleteError.
Action 16:01:04: SetupCompleteError. Dialog created
Action 16:01:52: CleanUpGUISequenceCA.
Action start 16:01:52: CleanUpGUISequenceCA.
Action ended 16:01:53: CleanUpGUISequenceCA. Return value 1.
Action ended 16:01:53: SetupCompleteError. Return value 2.
Action ended 16:01:53: INSTALL. Return value 3.
```

I have been given a windows 7 laptop and I basically can delete anything I want on it just to make this work. Problem is: I have no clue what it refers to. Are there registry keys to delete or something alike? (Or is there a "force install")

Comment: I've not worked with Windows installers for a while, but there typically are two options: "work with existing installation" and "install new"; you'll need to choose the latter.

Comment: See if this helps: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21104569

Comment: yes,no, it only give the option migrate so no other option like "install". In programs and features there is no Db2 something at all (except for the IBM Data client 4.1.2) (which is an eclipe product). So that is why i am looking on what to uninstall, undoubtly there is something but I have no clue what it would be.

Comment: Ok.... it was " Quest Data For Analysts", which is by default on these laptops. I uninstalled it and i got the option to install versus migrate. however now i get the next " major error during update"  etc

Comment: After downloading a VBA script to edit the .MSI file and remove a certain entry (and discovering it needed the complete path instead of the relative path) installation of client succeeded, thanks @mustaccio

Comment: Glad it finally worked. Too bad DB2 installers, particularly on Windows, don't get much love from the vendor.

Comment: unfortunately: SQL5048N  The release level of the database client is not supported by the release level of the database server. ... so I probably have to try an even older client.

Comment: 8.1 or 8.2 client will certainly work, but it probably won't install on Windows 7