# DB2 CLP connect to remote DB

Tags: db2

I downloaded and installed on Windows the following:

```
IBM DB2 Runtime Client (64-Bit) 10.5
```

with the aim of connecting to a remote server database.

It installed here:

```
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB
```

But I don't see any DB2 folders in there.

I tried to catalog the remote db like this:

```
db2 catalog tcpip node testing remote the.server.com server 446
```

If I then try to connect to it, I get the following:

```
SQL1031N  The database directory cannot be found on the indicated file system.
```

There is some wizard installed called the 'Default DB2 and IBM Database Client Interface Selection Wizard'.  I ran this and it said it would create a default DB2 copy and would be used by default, called DB2COPY1 and it would be installed to `C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB.`

But I'm nnot sure what this is doing really.

What do I need to do here to connect to the remote DB2??

***EDIT:***

I have managed to get a bit further based on this article here:
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21008914

my current commands look like:

```
db2 catalog tcpip node tstnode remote my.server.com server 446
db2 catalog db db1name as mytstdb at node tstnode authentication server
db2 catalog dcs db db1name as A123456DAT
db2 terminate
db2 connect to mytstdb user <username> using <password>
```

However the connect fails with:

```
SQL30061N  The database alias or database name "A123456DAT        " was not
found at the remote node.  SQLSTATE=08004
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `catalog tcpip node` is just registering remote db2 instance/subsystem. You must issue `catalog db mydb at node testing` in order to connect to the database `mydb`. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001936.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DB2 can't connect to the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17088241/db2-cant-connect-to-the-server)

Comment: I have updated my question, I'm not sure it is a duplicate

Comment: Ask your IBM i / Z/OS admin about the proper database name. `A123456DAT` is a wrong one.

Comment: Interesting, as I can connect to it through an application like IntelliJ using a connection string `jdbc:as400://my.server.com:446/A123456DAT;`  But through the clp I get the error

Answer (score 0):

If you are connecting through port 446, I guess you are trying to connect to DB2 for IBM z or DB2 for IBM i.  If yes, you will need at least Db2 Connect.

Regarding error "SQL30061N  The database alias or database name "A123456DAT        " was not found at the remote node.  SQLSTATE=08004" it happens to me when the userid does not have some priviledges on the source system. If it is an IBM i, look at the corresponding spool file.  DRDA Connections are attended by jobs called QRWTSRVR. With the IBM i command WRKSPLF SELECT(USERID) (changing USERID  by the user trying the DRDA connection) you can see the spool files for jobs related to your connection.  Usually spool file messages are very specific on the cause of the failure.

If you are trying to connect to DB2 on z, I don't have experience.

Comment: Any link to this?

Comment: I don't have reputation points enough to comment on your question.  But,  to check what Mark Barinstein said, ask your IBM i manager to execuite DSPRDBDIRE and verify the database name.  IBM i usually has only one database name but if they implement iASPs on your shop, they may have several.  On the other hand, ODBC on IBM i usually connects on ports 8471, 9471 (ssh), not 446, so, probably your connection string is jdbc:as400://my.server.com/mydbname;